# Bash script to monitor server security?

Tags: shell-script, security, monitoring

I am using a shared server at HG and I want to automate a bash script that will run hourly once and notify me to my gmail account with details of authorized/non-authorized users who have logged into the system in the past hour. HG doesn't allow tools like inotify in their shared plans. Is this possible? Do you think it's a decent idea?

Although I am the only user, what happens if someone illicitly logs in without my knowledge? The problem is I can't run `who` every time or scan the logs as it is a tedious process.

Comment: You can install a Intrusion Detection System. I recomand to you OSSEC.
Simple to use and very good reports.

Answer (score 0):

you can also parse `/var/log/secure` and check for successfull authentication. It's the way that fail2ban works.

With the correct file path, here you can use inotify to fetch data instently and send a mail on each connection or make a batch and parse the file. (if you use smartly logrotate you can significantly simplify your script).

Answer (score 0):

Just email the output of 'last' (previous logins; time in, time out, time logged on) and 'w' (currently logged in).

Comment: Sorry I'm not a full time coder rather a marketer. Can you please tell me what to do? Thanks.